# Unable to start executing the feature file that was created dynamically through Java API

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, cucumber

I'm creating a feature file programmatically using the following java code.

```
// This method will be invoked by 'constructFeatureFile()'
public static void createFeatureFile(String strFeatureFilePath, String strFeatureFileContent, String runnableFile)
{
    try
    {
        if (strFeatureFilePath.trim().length() > 0 && strFeatureFileContent.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            // First time file creation
            if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(strFeatureFilePath)))
            {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(strFeatureFilePath));
                Writer wr = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                wr.write(strFeatureFileContent);
                wr.close();
            } //If the exists, delete that file and create with fresh data
            else if(Files.exists(Paths.get(strFeatureFilePath)))
            {
                Files.delete(Paths.get(strFeatureFilePath));

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(strFeatureFilePath));
                Writer wr = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                wr.write(strFeatureFileContent);
                wr.close();
            }

            // Call Runner to run feature file
            runner(runnableFile);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

// Invoke feature file to execute
public static void runner(String runnableFile)
{
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    args.put("name", "API Testing");

    Map<String, Object> getResponse = CucumberRunner.runClasspathFeature(runnableFile, args, true);
    getResponse = null;
}
```

The problem is, after creating the **feature file**, I'm calling **Runner()** method to execute the feature file. Its throwing the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: file not found: country//getMembersDetails.feature
```

But, after refresing the folder (where the feature file was created), and re-run the same script, it's executing perfectly with the same feature file.

I don't understand why this is happening, what is the mistake I did here, anyone please provide suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: any updates? :(

Comment: When I run through "Debug Mode" it's working but when I execute Run As - JUnit Test option its throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm removing the karate tag as this is not a karate question.

Comment: If it works in debug them u might have a timing issue. Try putting in a sleep before you call the runner method.

Comment: Hi Grasshopper, your suggestion helped me...Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like createFeatureFile() is busy writing to strFeatureFilePath, but then calling runner(runnableFile).  nothing was written to runnableFile?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the 'runnableFile' variable, I'm passing the feature file classpath like "country//getMembersDetails.feature". The actual feature file location is "D:\Workspace\karatedemo\src\test\java\country\getMembersDetails.feature"